# Prepending location to static files in NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

two flask webapps, say a & b have to be hosted on production server.

have only one port, say 11111.

using nginx for proxy

`location /a/ {proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8000/;}
location /b/ {proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:7000/;}`

Now, while testing them on laptop (a.k.a local server), static file requests coming from port 8000 are served by :8000/static and,
static file requests coming from port 7000 are served by :7000/static

But now in case of production server, any request to /static files from either of the app hosted at /a and /b will go to :11111/static

but I want static files to be served by :11111/a/static and :11111/b/static respectively.

looking for best work arounds.

Comment: can you define two subdomains on production? then you can have two seperate server block to configure which gives you a lot of options to handle this

Comment: @shalbafzadeh, I can't have to subdomains. That's the problem.